# How to use UNNEST hint in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, tuning

I have encountered Bug 34044661 - Poor Performance Due to SQL Not Unnesting in Oracle 19C (Doc ID 34044661.8).

Oracle provides some workarounds:

```
use UNNEST hint
or
alter session set "_optimizer_squ_bottomup" = false;
or
alter session set "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation" = OFF;
```

The current execution plan (estimate plan is 19h to execute).

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name        | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 143 |   NESTED LOOPS                       |             |    307K|   135M|       |  1808M  (2)| 19:37:40 |
|*144 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | XXXX        |   2571K|  1054M|       | 49880   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|*145 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | BBBB        |      1 |    32 |       |   703   (2)| 00:00:01 |
```

After change "_optimizer_squ_bottomup" or "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation" (estimate plan is 05 secs to execute)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name        | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*146 |    HASH JOIN                         |             |    273K|   120M|    11M|   104K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|*147 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                | BBBB        |    273K|  8547K|       |   703   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*148 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                | XXXX        |   2571K|  1054M|       | 49880   (2)| 00:00:02 |
```

But I'd like to use the UNNEST hint. Where can I place this hint in the query? I haven't had any success so far to reach the second execution plan (without NESTED LOOPS).

The SQL is as follows (I've hidden some columns).

```
SELECT
 some columns,
 .....,
FROM XXXX AS FIN
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM BBBBB R1 WHERE R1.VVVV = 'F' AND R1.NNNN = FIN.NNNN)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BBBBB R1 WHERE R1.VVVV = 'E' AND R1.NNNN = FIN.DDDDD)
AND NOT (FIN.SSSS = 'S' AND FIN.EEEEEE IS NOT NULL AND FIN.VVVV='E')
 UNION ALL
SELECT
 some columns,
 .....,
FROM XXXX AS FIN
,BBBBB CCC
WHERE (--
(CCC.VVVV = 'F' AND CCC.NNNN = FIN.NUFIN) OR
(CCC.VVVV = 'E' AND CCC.NNNN = FIN.DDDDD)
)
AND NOT (FIN.SSSS = 'S' AND FIN.EEEEEE IS NOT NULL AND FIN.VVVV='E');
```

Comment: How do you know you have hit Bug 34044661? Anyway, [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Unnesting-of-Nested-Subqueries.html) suggest placing the hint in the relevant subquery, although they are a little light on detail.

Comment: We just upgraded from 11g to 19c, and the queries have significantly slowed down. Applying the workaround seemed to solve the problem. I believe we have encountered this bug. I already tried /*+ UNNEST */, but no change in execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

Typically `/*+ UNNEST */` is placed in the subquery.

Finding a seemingly better plan with `"_optimizer_squ_bottomup" = false` or `"_optimizer_cost_based_transformation" = OFF;` (especially this one) does not necessarily mean you have the specific problem the referenced note describes.

There is a huge difference between enabling/disabling a single transformation and disabling all cost-based transformations.